# PHP Array from YAML with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get PHP Array from parameters.yml in Symfony, example :

```
parameters:
    keek.color:
        blue:
            - color1
            - color2
        red:
            - color3
            - color4
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Does Symfony disallow you from using the YAML extension?

Comment: [How to set parameters in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/zxo6/how-to-set-parameters-in-symfony)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can retrieve with the method `getParameter` on the  container instance, as example:

```
$container->getParameter('keek.color');
```

In a controller with the shortcut:

```
    $this->getParameter('keek.color');
```

And will return an array:

```
array(2) {
  'blue' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "color1"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "color2"
  }
  'red' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "color3"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "color4"
  }
}
```