# Get array in parameters.yml from route with Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have parameters in my yml :

```
// myparameter.yml
parameters:
    keekbootstrap4.color:
        blue:
            - color1
            - color2
        red:
            - color1
            - color2
```

In my Controller, I want to get the "blue" key :

```
/**
 * @Route("/keekbootstrap4-card-{color}.css", requirements={"color" = "%keekbootstrap4.color%"}, name="keekbootstrap4_card")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    dump($this->container->getParameter('keekbootstrap4.color')[$color]);
```

But I have this error :

**The container parameter "keekbootstrap4.color", used in the route configuration value "%keekbootstrap4.color%", must be a string or numeric, but it is of type array.**

Can you help me ? It's possible to get array with key in Route url ? Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Array from YAML with Symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439734/php-array-from-yaml-with-symfony)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? If you're not happy with the provided answer you can edit your original post at any time to further clarify what your issue is and what your expected anwer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439734/php-array-from-yaml-with-symfony

Comment: I don't know if it will work but have you tried with `requirements={"color": "%keekbootstrap4.color.blue.0%"|"%keekbootstrap4.color.blue.1%"}` or `requirements={"color": "%keekbootstrap4.color.blue.0%|%keekbootstrap4.color.blue.1%"}`

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/service_container_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do it in this way:

```
/**
 * @Route("/keekbootstrap4-card-{color}.css", name="keekbootstrap4_card")
 */
public function indexAction($color)
{
    $colors = $this->getParameter('keekbootstrap4.color');

    if (!array_key_exists($color, $colors)) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    dump($colors[$color]);
}
```